# Which approach should I choose for testing my Spring Batch Job?

Tags: spring, testing, automated-tests, spring-batch, spring-test

Currently I'm working on some integration tests for a Spring Batch application. Such application reads from a **SQL** table, writes on another table and, at the end, generates a report as a `.txt` file.

Initially I thought of just assuring that I had another file with the expected output and compare it with the report file and check the table content.

(For some context, I'm not very experienced on **Spring**).

But, after reading some articles on [Baelung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-batch-testing-job), I'm having doubts about my initial methodology.

Should I manipulate the table content on my code to assure that I have the expected input? Should I use the **Spring** Test framework tools? Without them, I'm able to run the job from my test?

Comment: I added an answer, does it help?

Comment: Yeah, it does, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach for batch job integration testing is to test the job as a black box. If the job reads data from a table and writes to another table or a file, you can proceed as follows:

- Put some test data in the input table (Given)
- Run your job (When)
- Assert on the output table/file (Then)

You can find more details in the [End-To-End Testing of Batch Jobs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/testing.html#endToEndTesting) section of the reference documentation. Spring Batch provides some test utilities that might help in testing your jobs (like mocking batch domain objects, asserting on file content, etc). Please refer to the [org.springframework.batch.test](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/test/package-summary.html) package.